# Install GRASS GIS and use it with python in Linux machines?

Tags: python, linux, gis, grass

Is there a bash script to install GRASS GIS and use it with python in Linux machines?

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y install grass-dev
export GRASSBIN=$(which grass)
pip install grass-session
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y
source "$HOME/.cargo/env"
pip install pygrass
# >>> from grass_session import Session
# >>> import grass
```